# German word for Internet

Tags: etymology, technical-terminology, neologism

I wonder what could be the word for the "Internet", if it was created by Germans (lets say in early 60-ties)

Comment: If Germans would have invented the Internet, then they would probably given it an (in)audible acronym. Just look at all the institutes connected to CERN, who played a significant role in developing the www.

Comment: Did you know the TAE in German "TAE-Dose" means "Telefon-Anschluss-Einheit" and their F- and N-sockets are used to plug in devices for "Fernsprechen" and "Nicht-Fernsprechen"? Given that, I'd bet the internet would be called "Allgemeines Netzwerk zur Fernübermittlung von Kommunikationseinheiten", short ANFüK. And yes, I'm kidding.

Comment: @Perl Dog, I would love it. _Fuck, the fucking ANFuK does not work again._

Comment: @PerlDog Da wäre bestimmt noch "digital" drin - _Allgemeines Netzwerk zur Fernübermittlung der digitalen Kommunikationseinheiten_, short **_ANFüdK_**

Comment: Wir haben auch Telefon gesagt und nicht Fernsprecheinrichtung. TAE-Dose habe ich erst kennengelernt, als ich ein Modem an den eigenen Anschluss anschließen wollte.

Answer (score 3):

- The prefix »inter« is latin and means »between« in English and »zwischen« in German.
- English »net« and German »Netz« (both nouns) mean the same thing, and both derive from the same Proto-Germanic root »*natją«. Also German »nähen« (to sew) derives from it, and even the latin words »nodus« (*node* in english) and »nassa« (a fish trap) are etymological related words.

So a pure English word for »internet« would be: »between-net«, and a pure German word would be

> Zwischennetz

---

But the word »Internet« came only in use in the 1980ies. Before that time it was:

> internetwork

and even before it was

> arpanet

which was invented 1968, and »ARPANET« is an acronym for »Advanced Research Projects Agency NETwork«

If it would have been invented by a German speaking group (which also could be researchers from Austria or Switzerland), then they might have named it after their own group. So, think of any German name for a group of scientists, add »Netzwerk« to the end of that group-name and make an acronym of it, then you have what you are searching for.

Comment: One reference: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Internet

Comment: Oder Internetz, wie Intercity und Intershop.

Answer (score 2):

Internet stands for *International Network* (1,2) and the German translation is *Internationales Netzwerk*. However, from your question, I understand that you do not ask for a direct translation.

In case you ask for a direct translation, the name would be

> Internetz (**Inter**nationales **Netz**werk)

I think, the Germans would use a different name for it.
 My guess is;

> Verbundene Netzwerke

### Sources

**(1)** Leben in einer vernetzten Welt, Band 1 von Robert Korz (Seite 6)

[image]

**(2)** Computerlexikon von André Poppek (Seite 51)

[image]

Comment: »Inter« in »Internet« has nothing to do with »international«. It just means, that there is a network between (inter) the computers of universities and military (and later even private computers). When the name »internetwork« was invented, all linked computers was inside one country (all inside the USA). There was nothing international with it.

Comment: Interesting theory. Do you have references for it?

Comment: @Iris I have some but I am looking for more reliable ones. If I find, I will publish here.

Comment: @Iris The sources were added.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast You are right. The first founder could think like that but the things may change with the time. For example, in the past, SQL stands for **SeQueL** but now, **Structured Query Language**. Because, the new form represents the abbreviation better. In my perspective, **International Network** represents the Internet better than **Inter-Network**.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Almost. Today's "structured query language" was previously named "SEQUEL" (short for "Structured English Query Langauge"). But due to trademark issues it had to be renamed to "SQL" ("Structured Query Language"). To date I do not understand why people still pronounce it "SEQUEL", as there is is no `E` "between" `S` and `Q`. I'd understand if they said "SQUEL" or even "ESQUEL", but "SEQUEL"...

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Previously, I have watched a tutorial about DBMS and there was an old prof. He explained the issue there. He said that the older people like me say SEQUEL while younger generation say SQL. I think the reason is like some old people say "Deutsche Mark" instead of "Euro" to this day even if they mean "Euro".

Comment: The Korz definition of _www_ is completely wrong as well. The world wide web is all about Hypertext and URLs, and it's a more specialised use of the internet.

Answer (score 1):

The "Deutsche Bundespost" (state-owned telecom until liberalisation) used to have a wide area communications network based on the X.25 protocol in the 80ies to connect the financial industry and university campusses. That was called

> Datex-P

(a compound abbreviation of "Data exchange" and "paketorientiert")

The first publicly available interactive online service was called

> Bildschirmtext

or (abbreviated)

> Btx

So the internet with a German name could probably have been named like

> Datex-I

(for "international")

or

> Computertext

abbreviated to

> Ctx

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet)

> Sprachkritiker, wie beispielsweise verschiedene Sprachvereine und viele rechtsextreme Organisationen wie die NPD, verwenden anstelle des Worts Internet deutsche Wortschöpfungen wie **Weltnetz, Zwischennetz oder Internetz**.

Comment: Please note that actually *using* the term "Weltnetz" could be taken as a tacit endorsement of the world view of such extremist organisations, which you probably don't want (the NPD is basically the closest legal approximation of the NSDAP, the original Nazi party).

Comment: @KilianFoth  I couldn't even remotely have guessed that viewpoint.